# Moving embedded math symbols relative to line text

Tags: positioning, tex-core

Is there a way to manually move some symbol set in latex? I did a manual example in paint brush and painted some red horizontal lines to put some perspective. All my attempts at Tikz were terrible, as even with a 2D axis in hand, every attempt moves the origin to the "best fit location".

.[image: Example]

The goal is not to affect the next line spacing. Another example would be positioning some real small symbols upward, e.g., $\chi$. I founded a way usind `\scaleobj`, but i didn't wanted to really scale the letter, just positioning.

```
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand{\Chi}{\scaleobj{1.3}{\chi}}
```

Comment: If you want to not affect the line spacing, the best is to  use the code  `$\min_{k\le n}$`, which results in the subscript on the left, slightly lowered.

Comment: please always provoide a small but complete test document. But as Bernard says inline math textstyle is designed to avoid changing the line spacing but you appear to have forced the displaymath layout here.

Comment: Thats the point, i dont want $\min_{k\leqslant n}$ in that case (and i really forced \displaystyle here). But in general, i'd really want to move any symbol.

Comment: Moving symbols like this is likely to be disabled if your document is submitted for publication, and earn you the displeasure of copyeditors.  And, especially if the reader is a novice mathematician, it might cause confusion.